# What are contract Variables and how are they different from normal varables declaration

Tags: solidity, truffle, tokens, testrpc

```
   pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
   import DappToken;

    contract DappTokenSale {
       address admin;
       DappToken public tokenContract;

      function DappTokeSale(DappToken _tokenContract) public {

          admin = msg.sender;
}
    }
```

DappToken is my previous smartContract  why did we declare a varable type of contract how is it diffrent from other types why did we declared
**DappToken public tokenContract;**

Answer (score 0):

The variable `DappToken` is a user-defined variable and the variable `admin` is a primitive variable. I don't think there is any other difference between the two vaiables.

I am assuming you are following [this](http://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/code-your-own-cryptocurrency-on-ethereum) tutorial.

As you are accessing `transfer` function of `DappToken` contract in `buyTokens` and `endSale` method you need to import `DappToken` smart contract.

Hope it helps.

Comment: DappToken is the name of the smart contract i defined before in tutorial we are asked to name it is DappToken i don't know why i have imported also DappToken in  my smart contract

Comment: @VenkateshMuthyala, I have updated my answer. Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Smart contract types are basically [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) around addresses, that add convenient way to call smart contract methods no them.  They also add some type-safety on assignments and argument passing.  On low level

```
DappToken public tokenContract;
```

is the same as

```
address public tokenContract;
```

but you may call methods like `tokenContract.foo(...)` rather than like `DappToken (tokenContract).foo (...)`.